# Copy String from one pointer to another in same process and between 2 processes

Tags: c, pointers, ipc

So I was asked these 2 questions in my interview-

1-what if I have a code snippet like this in C what will be the output

```
char *ptr1=malloc(10);
ptr1="abc";
char *ptr2 = malloc(20);
ptr2="defghi";
strcpy(ptr1,ptr2);
printf("%s",ptr1);
```

I tried this one on my terminal after getting home and it was giving this error

```
[1]    7673 bus error  ./b.out
```

I would like to know how to copy the string in such a case from one pointer to another.

2- We have 2 processes A and B

This is the code in process A

```
char *ptr1=malloc(10);
ptr1="abc";
char *ptr2 = malloc(20);
ptr2="defghi";
strcpy(ptr1,ptr2);
```

now the address of ptr1 is passed to process B using interprocess communication and the code in process B is as follows (ptr1 is the address from process A)

```
char *ptr3=malloc(10);
ptr3=ptr1
printf("%s",ptr3);
```

What would be the output of this? If the ans is garbage value or error then in what way can we make ptr3 point to the string pointed by ptr1.

Comment: This code makes no sense.  You allocate memory to ptr1, then re-assign ptr1 to a constant string value.  This is fixed somewhere in memory.  You can't just then copy "defghi" into ptr1.

Comment: They are testing if you have any idea what the C code does. Plainly you failed the interview. In case 1 not only do you overwrite the `malloc` pointers with string literal pointers, and try to copy one string literal to another, but the one you are copying to (even if it were legal) is smaller.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I didn't get you as to why this code makes no sense.According to me  first we allocated some space to ptr1 then we filled in "abc" in that space we did the same for ptr2 and then tried to fill ptr1 chunk with what is present in ptr2 and then print the result.Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: @KaviKavi Please read more C tutorials and references, you seem to have a very murky view of what happens in a C program. "Allocate space to a pointer" makes no sense.

Comment: @unwind What I meant by "Allocate space to a pointer " is that  pointer points to  the first memory location of the memory chunk given by the malloc function.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KaviKavi Yes but then it doesn't point there anymore after the `ptr1="abc"`. That statement doesn't fill in the space you allocated, it changes where the pointer points to.

Comment: @KaviKavi in C you cannot copy a string by assigning its pointer as in `ptr1="abc";`. You need `strcpy(ptr1, "abc")` and so on.

Comment: @KaviKavi Sure, but you seem to expect the assignment operator (`=`) to do different things (change what `ptr1` points to, and change the contents of memory it points to) on different lines, which it really doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know how to copy the string in such a case from one pointer to another.

You can't.  Pointers do not contain strings, or their characters.  They can, however, *point to* null-terminated arrays of characters, i.e. strings.

Having that in mind, it is important to understand that here:

```
char *ptr1=malloc(10);
ptr1="abc";
```

you allocate block of memory (or try to do), assign its address to variable `ptr1`, and then immediately overwrite that pointer value with a pointer to the arrary represented by string literal `"abc"`.  The original pointer value is lost -- you leak that memory.  In particular, the assignment absolutely does not copy the characters of the literal into the allocated space.

Now be aware that attempting to modify any part of a string literal invokes undefined behavior, whether the modification is direct or indirect.  This:

```
strcpy(ptr1,ptr2);
```

constitutes an attempt to modify string literal `"abc"` indirectly via pointer `ptr1`.  If the question was "what is the output" then it was a trick question.  The program has undefined behavior -- it's output cannot be predicted, at least not from the C code alone.

---

The IPC case is a different trick question.  Pointer values are meaningful only in the context of the process in which the pointer was obtained.  If you pass that pointer to a different process via some form of IPC, there is no reason to suppose that it is valid in the receiving process.  Even if it happens to be valid, there's no telling what it points to.  If you want to send a string to another process then you must send the *characters*, not the pointer.